# GLM conversion from euler angles to quaternion and back does not hold

Tags: c++, quaternions, glm-math, euler-angles, openvr

I am trying to convert the orientation of an OpenVR controller that I have stored as a `glm::vec3` of Euler angles into a `glm::fquat` and back, but I get wildly different results and the in-game behavior is just wrong *(hard to explain, but the orientation of the object behaves normally for a small range of angles, then flips in weird axes)*.

This is my conversion code:

```
// get `orientation` from OpenVR controller sensor data

const glm::vec3 eulerAnglesInDegrees{orientation[PITCH], orientation[YAW], orientation[ROLL]};
debugPrint(eulerAnglesInDegrees);

const glm::fquat quaternion{glm::radians(eulerAnglesInDegrees)};
const glm::vec3 result{glm::degrees(glm::eulerAngles(quaternion))};
debugPrint(result);

// `result` should represent the same orientation as `eulerAnglesInDegrees`
```

I would expect `eulerAnglesInDegrees` and `result` to either be the same or equivalent representations of the same orientation, but that is apparently not the case. These are some example values I get printed out:

```
39.3851 5.17816 3.29104 
39.3851 5.17816 3.29104 

32.7636 144.849 44.3845 
-147.236 35.1512 -135.616 

39.3851 5.17816 3.29104 
39.3851 5.17816 3.29104 

32.0103 137.415 45.1592 
-147.99 42.5846 -134.841
```

As you can see above, for some orientation ranges the conversion is correct, but for others it is completely different.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I've looked at existing questions and attempted a few things, including trying out [every possible rotation order listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27497022/598696), [conjugating the quaternion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29992778/598696), and other random things like flipping pitch/yaw/roll. Nothing gave me the expected result.

**How can I convert euler angles to quaternions and back, representing the original orientation, using `glm`?**

---

Some more examples of discrepancies:

```
original:      4; 175;   26; 
computed:   -175;   4; -153; 
difference:  179; 171;  179; 

original:     -6; 173;   32; 
computed:    173;   6; -147; 
difference: -179; 167;  179; 

original:      9; 268;  -46; 
computed:   -170; -88;  133; 
difference:  179; 356; -179; 

original:    -27; -73;  266; 
computed:    -27; -73;  -93; 
difference:    0;   0;  359; 

original:    -33; 111;  205; 
computed:    146;  68;   25; 
difference: -179;  43;  180;
```

I tried to find a pattern to fix the final `computed` results, but it doesn't seem like there's one easy to identify.

---

GIF + video of the behavior:

[image: Video excerpt]

- [Full video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSXpWEYKCYU)

---

Visual representation of my intuition/current understanding:

[image: Visual diagram]

- The above picture shows a sphere, and I'm in the center. When I aim the gun towards the green half of the sphere, the orientation is correct. When I aim the gun towards the red half of the sphere, it is incorrect - it seems like every axis is inverted, but I am not 100% sure that is the case.

Comment: running into gimbal lock problem of Euler angles. It's better to make camera control as a quaternion or a constrained reference frame angles. Some rotations have more than one set of Euler angles, with 180 degree turn having infinite amount of possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly following [tony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177923/tony)'s [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60348678/598696) and after some trial&error and pattern identification, I managed to figure out a way to restore the original values after the conversion.

- `ox`, `oy`, and `oz` are the original *pitch*, *yaw*, and *roll* in degrees, before any conversion;
- `fx`, `fy`, and `fz` are the new *pitch*, *yaw*, and *roll* in degrees, obtained after converting "Euler -> quaternion -> Euler" (via `glm::degrees(glm::eulerAngles(glm::normalize(quaternion)))`).

```
if (oy > 90.f)
{
    fx -= 180.f;
    fy -= 180.f;
    fy *= -1.f;
    fz += 180.f;

    if (ox > 0.f)
    {
        fx += 360.f;
    }
}
```

The above code seems to make the original angle values and the one after the conversion match exactly. While it answers the original question, it doesn't solve my actual issue... I was converting to a quaternion in order to smoothly interpolate to another angle. However, it seems that using `glm::mix` on the quaternion after the conversion results - again - in very unpredictable rotations.

Answer (score 4):

32.7636 144.849 44.3845 
-147.236 35.1512 -135.616

Those are the same. Left 33 or right 147. You are 180 from each other. Now look up 145 - that's past up that's 35 from horizon, your back is arched.
Now roll to get your back to the sky.

If you *need* to use Euler, try to keep pitch in -90 to +90, and  roll in -180 to +180;

```
if (pitch > 90) {
   pitch -= 90;
   yaw += 180;
   roll += 180;
}
if (roll > 180) {
   roll = 360 - roll;
}
```

or something like that.

Comment: pitch, yaw, roll aren't euler angles, it's positional angles and their application depends on type of reference frame :P

Comment: right, Yaw/Pitch/Roll is like YXZ Euler in object reference frame.  Whatever order (and reference) my advice would be similar - keep the angles constrained.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the any kind of 3 angles to represent a rotation is not only given by the order of the rotations, if they are extrinsic or extrinsic, but also which interval of angles you choose when you define the mapping of every element of the [3D Rotation Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group) to a tuple of 3 angles.

Unfortunately, it is common for software libraries to fail to explicit mention which subset of angles they support, so typically it is necessary to either test their behaviour or to direct inspect the source code. For a relevant issue regarding glm see https://github.com/g-truc/glm/issues/569, and see  https://github.com/robotology/idyntree/pull/504 for a related discussion on another library on which I work.

In glm `master`, from a quick inspection of the code (https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/6543cc9ad1476dd62fbfbe3194fcf19412f0cbc0/glm/gtc/quaternion.inl#L10) and from the fact that in C++ [`asin` image is roughly (-90.0, 90.0)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/asin) and [`atan2` image is roughly (-180.0, 180.0)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan), the assumed interval in glm seems to be roughly (-180.0, 180.0) x (-90.0, 90.0) x (-180.0, 180.0), so by limiting the **second angle** (the yaw, using the names that  you are using) to (-90.0, 90.0). So, what you are seeing at the GLM level is basically a mapping from the provided angles to equivalent angles in the (-180.0, 180.0) x (-90.0, 90.0) x (-180.0, 180.0) range.

However, the fact that this angles are equivalent depends on **how they are used**, i.e. if you have a library that **clamps** the euler angles outside the used ranges, instead of converting it to equivalent angles,  then you will obtain  strange results. For this reason, I think it would be interesting to understand your problem to know how this angles are generated (the middle angles in particular seems to be part of the range (-90, 270) that is a strange, even if valid choice) and how they are interpreted to render the object in the visualization. Once you understand that, even if the rendering function works fine for angles in the original applications ranges, you can  write a function to map "original application angles" to "GLM angles" and its inverse, that you can use for your original purpose.